# How to send the High priority push notification through AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

We need to send the high priority push notification to android mobile using Amazon SNS service.

We are able to send the normal priority messages, but we could not include the priority attribute in the message.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, please provide more context such as message contents and the error you received

Comment: There is no error, we just want to add the flag '"priority":"HIGH"' in the data message. As mentioned in the FCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: @AXE : called fcm API directly. Instead of SNS

Answer (score 2):

It is poorly documented but here is how it worked out.

Make sure several things are in place:

1. You SNS client publishes message with MessageStructure='json' attribute
2. You have "default" version of the message in the SNS payload
3. You serialize into string anything in the custom payload keys.

Python example would look like this

```
sns: SNSClient = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')
message = json.dumps(
    {
        "default": json.dumps(
            {
                "priority": "high",
                "data": {"my": "custom", "payload": "here"},
                "notification": {
                    "title": "Ukraine is awesome",
                    "body": "Ukraine is awesome",
                },
            }
        ),
        "GCM": json.dumps(
            {
                "priority": "high",
                "data": {"my": "custom", "payload": "here"},
                "notification": {
                    "title": "Ukraine is awesome",
                    "body": "Ukraine is awesome",
                },
            }
        ),
    }
)

response = sns.publish(
    TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC,
    Message=message,
    MessageStructure='json',
)
```